# How to Copy an EMF File to the Clipboard in Windows Using Python?

Tags: python, windows, clipboard, .emf

I'm trying to copy an EMF (Enhanced Metafile) file directly to the Windows clipboard using the `win32clipboard` module on Python3.12. but I'm facing an issue where `SetClipboardData` is throwing an "invalid handle" error. Here is the code I'm trying:

```py
import win32clipboard

def copy_emf_to_clipboard(emf_file_path):
    with open(emf_file_path, 'rb') as f:
        emf_data = f.read()

    try:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
        win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_ENHMETAFILE, emf_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

copy_emf_to_clipboard('input.emf')
```

When executing this code, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred: (6, 'SetClipboardData', 'The handle is invalid.')
```

Could someone explain why this error is occurring and how to properly copy the EMF data to the clipboard? Are there any specific steps or clipboard formats that I need to follow when dealing with EMF files?